# jquery next() reference to specific ul's li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a multi stage form with the following enabling the next/previous button to transit the form submission from one stage to the other:

```
$("input[name='next']").click(function(){
    var output = validate();
    if(output) {
        var current = $("#signup-step.active");
        var next = current .next(); //Just use .next() here to get the nextSibling of this li
        if(next.length>0) {
            $("#"+current.attr("id")+"-field").hide();
            $("#"+next.attr("id")+"-field").show();
            $("input[name='back']").show();
            $("input[name='finish']").hide();
            $(".active").removeClass("active");
            next.addClass("active");
           /* if($(".active").attr("id") == $("#signup-step.li").last().attr("id")) {
                $("input[name='next']").hide();
                $("input[name='finish']").show();               
            } */

            if ( next.is(':last-child') ) {
                $("input[name='next']").hide();
                $("input[name='finish']").show(); 
            }
        }
    }
});

$("input[name='back']").click(function(){ 
    var current = $(".active");
    var prev = $(".active").prev("#signup-step.li");
    if(prev.length>0) {
        $("#"+current.attr("id")+"-field").hide();
        $("#"+prev.attr("id")+"-field").show();
        $("input[name='next']").show();
        $("input[name='finish']").hide();
        $(".active").removeClass("active");
        prev.addClass("active");
        /*if($(".active").attr("id") == $("#signup-step.li").first().attr("id")) {
            $("input[name='back']").hide();         
        }
        */

        if ( next.is(':last-child') ) {
                $("input[name='back']").hide();  
            }
    }
});
```

By #signup-step:li I'm trying to refer to the li elements in a specific UL element because there two other UL element on the page: 1) UL of main menu, 2) UL of sidebars. Now since the main menu's UL comes before the form itself, the next/back button activate the menu items of the main menu rather the form stages. So being able to specify the UL referred will resolve this.

Kindly advise on the the correct for mat for selecting #signup-step:li in the code above?

Here is the form:

```
<ul id="signup-step">
    <li id="Initiate" class="active">Initiate</li>
    <li id="Strive">Strive</li>
    <li id="End">End</li>
</ul>

<form name="frmRegistration" id="signup-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="sendemail.php">

    <div id="initiate-field">

        <label>Name of Organization</label><span id="coyname-error" class="signup-error"></span>
        <div><input type="text" name="coyname" id="coyname" class="demoInputBox"/></div>
        <label>Certificate of Incorporation No.</label><span id="cacnum-error" class="signup-error"></span>
        <div><input type="text" name="cacnum" id="cacnum" class="demoInputBox"/></div>
        <label>Registered Office Address</label><span id="regofficeaddy-error" class="signup-error"></span>
        <div>

        <textarea  cols="30" rows="4" name="regofficeaddy" id="regofficeaddy"  class="demoInputBox" class = "max10"></textarea>

        </div>
        <label>Operations Address</label><span id="opsaddy-error" class="signup-error"></span>
        <div>

        <textarea  cols="30" rows="4" name="opsaddy" id="opsaddy"  class="demoInputBox" class = "max10"></textarea>

        </div>
</div>

<div id="strive-field" style="display:none;">
        <label>Location of workshop/facility if different from office address given in the Structure Section:</label><span id="facilityloc-error" class="signup-error"></span>
        <div>

        <textarea cols="60" rows="8" name="facilityloc" id="facilityloc"  class="demoInputBox" class = "max10"></textarea>


        </div>


        <label>Size of facility (in sq meters):</label><span id="facilitysize-error" class="signup-error"></span>
        <div><input type="text" name="facilitysize" id="facilitysize" class="demoInputBox"/></div>
        <label>Does your organization own or hire equipment:</label>
        <div>

        <input type="radio" name="facilityownhire" id="facilityownhire" value="Own"> Own
        <input type="radio" name="facilityownhire" id="facilityownhire" value="Hire"> Hire <span id="facilityownhire-error" class="signup-error"></span>

        </div>

</div>

<div id="end-field" style="display:none;">


        <label>Does your Organization have an HSE Manual?</label>
        <div>

        <input type="radio" name="hsemanual" id="hsemanual" value="Yes"> Yes
        <input type="radio" name="hsemanual" id="hsemanual" value="No"> No <span id="hsemanual-error" class="signup-error"></span>

        </div>

        <div id="hseevidenceBOX">
            <label>If yes, please attach evidence</label><span id="hseevidence-error" class="signup-error"></span>
            <div>   
            <input type="file" name="vendorfile[]"  id="hseevidence"  class="demoInputBox" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <label>Does your Organization have a Safety Policy?</label>
        <div>

        <input type="radio" name="orgsafepolicy" id="orgsafepolicy" value="Yes"> Yes
        <input type="radio" name="orgsafepolicy" id="orgsafepolicy" value="No"> No <span id="orgsafepolicy-error" class="signup-error"></span>

        </div>
</div>
<div>
        <input class="btnAction" type="button" name="back" id="back" value="Back" style="display:none;">
        <input class="btnAction" type="button" name="next" id="next" value="Next">
        <input class="btnAction" type="submit" name="finish" id="finish" value="Send" style="display:none;">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: What is your HTML? If you post this we can help you

Comment: what is `#signup-step:li ` supposed to select? if the `<li>` element has the id  `signup-step`, just type `$('#signup-step')`

Comment: <ul id="signup-step">
 <li id="structure" class="active">Initiate</li>
 <li id="infrastructure">Strive</li>
 <li id="hse">End</li>
</ul>

Comment: Place the relevant HTML in your question please, not the comments.

Comment: I've done that. Thank you.

Comment: @Alex the HTML is <ul id="signup-step"><li></li>, that is signup-step is the id of UL

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for responding. I solve the problem of conflict with the main menu of the page I change the .active class to .here in the UL HTML, CSS and jquery script. I also reliazed from this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/GrahamWalters/sgNH4/2/ i gained from another thread that the next("#signup-step.li"); should be next("#signup-step li");

UL HTML

```
<ul id="signup-step">
    <li id="Initiate" class="active">Initiate</li>
    <li id="Strive">Strive</li>
    <li id="End">End</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
#signup-step li.here{background-color:#FF0000;}
.here{color:#FFF;}
```

JQUERY

```
$("#next").click(function(){
        var output = validate();
        if(output) {
            var current = $(".here");
            var next = $(".here").next("#signup-step li");
            if(next.length>0) {
                $("#"+current.attr("id")+"-field").hide();
                $("#"+next.attr("id")+"-field").show();
                $("#back").show();
                $("#finish").hide();
                $(".here").removeClass("here");
                next.addClass("here");
                if($(".here").attr("id") == $("#signup-step li").last().attr("id")) {
                    $("#next").hide();
                    $("#finish").show();                
                }
            }
        }
    });
    $("#back").click(function(){ 
        var current = $(".here");
        var prev = $(".here").prev("#signup-step li");
        if(prev.length>0) {
            $("#"+current.attr("id")+"-field").hide();
            $("#"+prev.attr("id")+"-field").show();
            $("#next").show();
            $("#finish").hide();
            $(".here").removeClass("here");
            prev.addClass("active");
            if($(".here").attr("id") == $("li").first().attr("id")) {
                $("#back").hide();          
            }
        }
    });
```